# User's shell is (apparently) adding lines to a shell script during execution

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My bash shell script has the following lines:

(Line numbers added)

```
1] printf "   Username:"; 
2] read USERNAME; 
3] 
4] WGET=`which wget`;
5] $WGET -V >& /dev/null;
6] STATUS=$?;
```

This is run by hundreds of users and thoroughly tested. When a particular user runs the script, the output of "sh -x" shows some lines being executed which are not in the original script:

(line numbers added)

```
1] + printf '   Username:'
2]    Username:
3] + read SSO_USERNAME
4] + tput cuu1
5] + 2> /dev/null
6] .sh.subscript=$'\E[A'
7]
8] + which wget
9] + WGET=/usr/bin/wget
10]+ /usr/bin/wget -V
11]+ update/wget.sh[31]: /dev/null: bad file unit number
12]+ STATUS=1
```

User is executing using putty with kerberos authentication and "ksu".

Where are lines 4 and 6 in the user output coming from and why?

Comment: `which` is a shell script, so it runs the user's `.bashrc`. His `.bashrc` executes those commands.

Comment: Those things probably should only be done in interactive shells, but he doesn't have appropriate conditionals in his `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Barmar : Thank you so much.. checking on that.

Comment: @Inian : I will look into that as well, thank you!

Comment: @Inian It is, see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) - just not used as often as `&>`. The manual says the the `&>` form is "preferred".

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Thanks for clarifying that! Appreciate it!

Comment: My first, naive thought is that the user simply is not executing the same script. Line 3 is also suspect in that the variable name is not the same, and line 4 looks very much like a `ksh`-specific extension.

Comment: In the sample output, have you trimmed leading + symbols?  I don't understand why there is only one `+` in line 8.

Comment: @Barmar : "which" is not a shell script: 

$ file /usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped 

Maybe it is on some OS's(?)

Comment: @WilliamPursell : here, unfiltered "sh -x" output (in case I messed it up in my OP) 

+ printf '   Username:'
   Username:+ read USERNAME
+ tput cuu1
+ 2> /dev/null
+ .sh.subscript=$'\E[A'

+ which wget
+ WGET=/usr/bin/wget
+ /usr/bin/wget -V
+ update/wget.sh[31]: /dev/null: bad file unit number
+ STATUS=1

Comment: @kmantic It's a shell script on my Debian system: `barmar@dev:~$ file /usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which: symbolic link to /bin/which
barmar@dev:~$ file /bin/which
/bin/which: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable`

Comment: @Barmar: .bashrc is only sourced for interactive shell, When the user is calling it as a shell script (i.e. **not** sourcing it), .bashrc is not loaded.